# Nginx reverse proxy when port is already in use?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, reverse-proxy, unix, prometheus

i am trying to close port with basic authentication (for pushgateway of prometheus), so not a big specialist in nginx, so could someone please give me and advice where i am is wrong?

I have 9091 port, that should be closed from outside in front of auth. This port is under use by pushgateway

My current nginx config :

```
events { }
http {
upstream prometheus {
      server 127.0.0.1:9090;
      keepalive 64;
}

upstream pushgateway {
      server 127.0.0.1:9091;
      keepalive 64;
}

server {
      root /var/www/example;
      listen 0.0.0.0:80;
      server_name __;      
      location / {
            auth_basic "Prometheus server authentication2";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
            proxy_pass http://prometheus;
      }  
}


server {
      root /var/www/example;
      listen 0.0.0.0:3001;          
      server_name __;      
      location / {
            auth_basic "Pushgateway server authentication";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
            proxy_pass http://pushgateway;
      } 
}
}
```

So basic authentication works fine for :3001, but 9091 still open. I tried to change it next way :

```
   server {
      root /var/www/example;
      listen 0.0.0.0:3001;
      listen 0.0.0.0:9091;
      server_name __;      
      location / {
            auth_basic "Pushgateway server authentication";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
            proxy_pass http://pushgateway;
      } 
}
```

And works fine, but ... pushgateway can't start as  trying to listen :9091 and throwing "bind:address is already in use". How can i avoid it and hide pushgateway in front of nginx?

Pushgatewa's config :

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/pushgateway --web.listen-address=":9091" --web.telemetry-path="/metrics"  --persistence.file="/tmp/metric.store"  --persistence.interval=5m --log.level="info" --log.format="logger:stdout?json=true"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current nginx configuration is good for this purpose.

You need to change your Pushgateway configuration so that it listens to `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`.

If you cannot find that, then you need to add a firewall rule that blocks traffic to the port from WAN side.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. It was i tried first. ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/pushgateway --web.listen-address="127.0.0.1:9091" --web.telemetry-path="/metrics"  --persistence.file="/tmp/metric.store"  --persistence.interval=5m --log.level="info" --log.format="logger:stdout?json=true", issue the same

Comment: What does `ss -lnpt | grep gateway` show?

Comment: It is with commented nginx line with listen 9091 : https://i.imgur.com/nA71xlt.png, with listening - it showing nothing as pushgateway can't start : https://i.imgur.com/2AMCyFs.png

Comment: You must not have the second configuration snippet in your question. nginx must not listen to that port.

Comment: Ok, but what i need to do to make this port not accessible from public access?

Comment: I have already told what to do. You use only the first part configuration in your question, and then configure Pushgateway to listen to only `127.0.0.1:9091`. This way, only Pushgateway is listening to port 9091, and since it is bound to localhost, it is not available externally.

Comment: Yeap... you are totaly right. Looks like when i tested 127.0.0.1:9091 - i did not restarted service correctly. rebooting whole node fixed it. Thank you a lot, man.